# Compiling C++ code with GCC on macOS Monetary Gives Warning

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, homebrew, macos-monterey

dylib (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0)
whenever I compile any c++ or c code I get this warning
my gcc installed version is g++-11
can anyone tell me how to fix this warning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.